# Is the collection of reduced points in a complex space is open?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

A point $x$ in a complex (analytic) space $(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$ is said to be reduced if $\mathcal{O}_{X.x}$ is a reduced ring i.e. it doesn't have any non-zero nilpotent elements. Defined the set $S=\{x\in X\mid x\,\text{is a reduced point of}\,(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})\}$. Is $S$ necessarily an open subset of $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is!

For exact, the set of non-reduced points of a complex analytic space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is an *analytic set*, and these sets are **canonically** closed complex analytic subspace of $X$; so the set of reduced points of $X$ is open.

See H. Grauert, R. Remmert (1984) *Coherent Analytic Sheaves*, Springer-Verlag; chapter 4, §1.1 and §3.1.